# How To Record The Index Of Training and Testing Data For Analysis After Training (keras and python)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I essentially want to tag each of the targets so that afterward, I can analyze each sample individually. This way I can look at that sample in much greater detail. I have a dataset and I split into training, validation, and testing sets.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


ins = np.load('ins.npy')
ins.shape
# (100,12,60,60)
type(ins)
# <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

And then I send it through the training. I assume here I need to attach another np array that gives identifying information about the sample.

```
ins_train, ins_test , outs_train, outs_test = train_test_split(ins, outs, test_size=0.25, random_state=3)
ins_train, ins_val, outs_train, outs_val = train_test_split(ins_train, outs_train, test_size =0.2, random_state=2)
```

However, I do use a generator to send this data through a keras neural network. Should I provide that code as well? I will provide some, let me know if more is needed.

Here I make the generator:

```
def training_set_generator_images(ins, outs, batch_size=10,
                          input_name='input', 
                        output_name='output'):
    '''
    Generator for producing random minibatches of image training samples.
    
    @param ins Full set of training set inputs (examples x row x col x chan)
    @param outs Corresponding set of sample (examples x nclasses)
    @param batch_size Number of samples for each minibatch
    @param input_name Name of the model layer that is used for the input of the model
    @param output_name Name of the model layer that is used for the output of the model
    '''
   
    while True:
        # Randomly select a set of example indices
        example_indices = random.choices(range(ins.shape[0]), k=batch_size)
        
        # The generator will produce a pair of return values: one for inputs and one for outputs
        yield({input_name: ins[example_indices,:,:,:]},
             {output_name: outs[example_indices,:,:,:]})
```

I create a keras neural network. I assume any neural network would do, but I'm not sure.

```
model = create_uNet(ins_train.shape[1:])
# call the generator
generator = training_set_generator_images(ins_train, outs_train,batch_size=50,
                        input_name='input',
                        output_name='output')
```

And then we fit the model.

```
history = model.fit(x=generator,epochs=1000)
# and we save the results
results = {}
results['predict_training'] = model.predict(ins_train)
results['predict_training_eval'] = model.evaluate(ins_train, outs_train)
results['true_training'] = outs_train
results['predict_validation'] = model.predict(ins_val)
results['predict_validation_eval'] = model.evaluate(ins_val, outs_val)
results['true_validation'] = outs_val
results['true_testing'] = outs_test
results['predict_testing'] = model.predict(ins_test)
results['predict_testing_eval'] = model.evaluate(ins_test, outs_test)
results['history'] = history.history
```

Within results['true_testing'] are the truths for the test set, and results['predict_testing'] are the corresponding predictions for the test set. For this to work, each example `results['predict_testing'][i]` will need to have, in addition to the image, but also the identifying information (in our case, a timestamp). Or there could be 3 dictionaries:

```
results['training_timestamps'] = training_timestamps
results['validation_timestamps'] = validation_timestamps
results['testing_timestamps'] = testing_timestamps
```

Please let me know if you need more information. It seems like the solution might be quick and easy, but the generator throws me off.

Comment: Does the docs of `train_test_split` discus this issue?

Comment: I strongly suggest you use pytorch. Doing nonstandard analysis and development of new tools is much easier there than tensorflow.

Comment: @hpaulj it does not.

Comment: @yannziselman Do you mean to use pytorch for splitting into training and testing data, or to use it for the whole thing (neural net and all)?

Comment: Can you apply `train_test_split` to `np.arange(N-samples)` using the same random_state?

Comment: @hpaulj you are correct. I can write an answer or you can if you'd like.

Comment: @hpaulj sorry, i thought he meant he whats to record the indices of all training samples passed through the model in each consecutive iteration during training, not just the overall indices of the train and test data. How would one accomplish what i thought he wanted to do? in torch it is trivial, just make your dataset pass the indices with the input and expected output.